# CRON job not working after 12 am midnight?

Tags: php, cron

please have a look at my website locpage. This is an add posting website where we schedule add depend on user requirement and add is autoreposted according to there time and date everyday or every hour. But if any add after posted after 24:00 then will not updated anymore till 10:00 i don't know what issue is coming provide me best possible solution.

```
date_default_timezone_set("Asia/kolkata");
 $curtime = date('h:i A');
 $ct =  $curtime = date('H:i' );

 $check_date=date('Y-m-d');


$querymoveother=$this->db->query("Select t1.*,t2.* from tbl_upgrades t1,tbl_listing t2 where  ((t1.autorepost_startdate ='".$check_date."'
OR t1.autorepost_enddate ='".$check_date."') AND t1.autorepost_counter < (t1.no_of_times)
 and (t1.autorepost_time <='".$ct."') AND (t1.autorepost_counterdate < '".$check_date."'
  OR t1.autorepost_counterdate < '0000-00-00' ) and (t1.autorepost_expirydate >='".$check_date."')) and (t1.list_id=t2.list_id) and t2.cat_id = '".$catid."' and (t2.list_city='".$_SESSION['cityid']."' OR FIND_IN_SET( '".$_SESSION['cityid']."', t1.nearbycities ))
  and t2.list_status='Enabled' ".$subcatqry." ".$keywords." and (t1.move_adtop_hr!='' OR t1.autorepost_day != '')    or (('".date("Y-m-d")."' between upgrade_date and expiry_date) AND move_adtop_hr!='' and (expiry_time <='".$ct."'  or   upgrade_time <= '".$ct."'  ) ) and (t1.list_id=t2.list_id) and t2.cat_id = '".$catid."' and (t2.list_city='".$_SESSION['cityid']."' OR FIND_IN_SET( '".$_SESSION['cityid']."', t1.nearbycities ))
  and t2.list_status='Enabled' ".$subcatqry." ".$keywords." and (t1.move_adtop_hr!=t1.countermove)  group by t1.list_id ORDER BY t1.upgrade_time desc,t1.autorepost_counterdate desc,t1.upgrade_id DESC ");

  $resultss = $querymoveother->result();
//echo $this->db->last_query();
$items = array();
        foreach($resultss as $getlist)
        {    echo "Other";


            $items[] = $getlist->list_id;
              $locquery = $this->db->query("select t1.*, t2.*, t3.* from tbl_country t1, tbl_state t2, tbl_city t3 where t1.country_id = '".$getlist->list_country."' AND t2.state_id = '".$getlist->list_state."' AND t3.city_id = '".$getlist->list_city."'")->row();

              $allimg = explode(",",$getlist->list_images);
              $totimgs = count($allimg);
              $firstimg = $allimg[0];
              if($firstimg=='')
              {
                $firstimg = 'noimage.png';
              }
              $subdomain = $newurllink;

              $getdata = $this->db->query("select t1.*, t2.* from tbl_category t1, tbl_subcategory t2 where t1.cat_id = '".$getlist->cat_id."' and t2.subcat_id = '".$getlist->subcat_id."'");

              $catstring1 = preg_replace('/[^\w]/', '-', $getdata->row()->cat_name);
              $newcatlink1 = str_replace("--","",strtolower($catstring1));

              $subcatstring1 = preg_replace('/[^\w]/', '-', $getdata->row()->subcat_name);
              $newsubcatlink1 = str_replace("--","",strtolower($subcatstring1));

              $listtitles1 = preg_replace('/[^\w]/', '-', $getlist->list_title);
              $newlisttitle = str_replace("--","",strtolower($listtitles1));
        ?>

         <?php if($getlist->amount!='' AND($getlist->move_adtop_hr!='' OR $getlist->sponsoramt!='' OR $getlist->autorepost_day!='')){
            $chk_status =$this->db->get_where("tbl_payment",array("itemnumber"=>$getlist->list_id,"paystatus"=>'Completed'));
            //echo $chk_status->num_rows();
            if($chk_status->num_rows()>0){
          ?>
               <div class="item-list">
                  <div class="col-sm-12 add-desc-box">
                    <div class="add-details">
                      <h5 class="add-title" style="overflow-wrap: break-word;"><a class="anchor-color" href="<?php echo $subdomain;?><?php echo $newcatlink1;?>/<?php echo $newsubcatlink1;?>/<?php echo $newlisttitle;?>/<?php echo $getlist->list_id;?>"><?php echo substr($getlist->list_title,0,50) ;?></a><span class="item-location"> (<?php echo $locquery->city_name.', '.$locquery->country_name;?>)</span></h5>
                      <p><?php echo substr($getlist->list_description,0,50).'..........';?></p>
                       <span class="date"><i class="fa fa-clock-o" aria-hidden="true"></i> <?php if($getlist->autorepost_counter>0){ echo  date("D. d M, Y",strtotime($getlist->autorepost_counterdate));}else{ echo  date("D. d M, Y",strtotime($getlist->normal_startdate)); }?> </span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                </div>
              <?php }}
```

Keyword and subcategory values

Select t1.*,t2.* from tbl_upgrades t1,tbl_listing t2 where ((t1.autorepost_startdate ='2018-04-23' OR t1.autorepost_enddate ='2018-04-23') AND t1.autorepost_counter < (t1.no_of_times) and (t1.autorepost_time <='10:53') AND (t1.autorepost_counterdate < '2018-04-23' OR t1.autorepost_counterdate < '0000-00-00' ) and (t1.autorepost_expirydate >='2018-04-23')) and (t1.list_id=t2.list_id) and t2.cat_id = '2' and (t2.list_city='742' OR FIND_IN_SET( '742', t1.nearbycities )) and t2.list_status='Enabled' and t2.subcat_id = '5' and (t1.move_adtop_hr!='' OR t1.autorepost_day != '') or (('2018-04-23' between upgrade_date and expiry_date) AND move_adtop_hr!='' and (expiry_time <='10:53' or upgrade_time <= '10:53' ) ) and (t1.list_id=t2.list_id) and t2.cat_id = '2' and (t2.list_city='742' OR FIND_IN_SET( '742', t1.nearbycities )) and t2.list_status='Enabled' and t2.subcat_id = '5' and (t1.move_adtop_hr!=t1.countermove) group by t1.list_id ORDER BY t1.upgrade_time desc,t1.autorepost_counterdate desc,t1.upgrade_id DESC

Comment: You should a) narrow this down to just the relevant code, b) tell us what the values of things like `$subcatqry` and `$keywords` are (and where they're set), c) show us your cron config for this task, and d) do some debugging/logging to see where things are crapping out.

Comment: Side note: Why is your cron outputting HTML to the browser? There won't *be* a browser when it's being cronned.

Comment: i posted value of $keyword and $subcategory please check